# How to cancel the sortchange event of an ExtJS grid?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I'm implementing a multi-sort for a grid. I want to use the `sortchange` event for this, but I have to cancel the event so I can call the store with my own sorting config.

This didn't work:

```
oGrid.on('sortchange', function(oColumnContainer, oColumn, strSortOrder){
  //...
  return false;
})
```

Comment: This is going to be quite complicated.  Are you willing to extend the column class for a solution?  If so I can show you how.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution by myself.

When I need my multi-sort, I set all columns on the grid to `sortable: false` at creation time (seems like it is not possible to do this on-the-fly)

Then I set a `on('headerclick`, function() {...})` to all the column-objects right after I created the grid.

The `sortable: false` prevents the click event on the header from sorting the table, but later I can still call `sort()` on the store programatically with the saved columns.

```
var oGrid = Ext.create( 'Ext.grid.Panel', {
  ...
  columns: [
    { ..., sortable: false }
  ]
});

for( i in oGrid.columns ) {
  oGrid.columns[i].on('headerclick', function(){...});
}
```